# Executing a VBA macro using the HYPERLINK function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to  populate a column with hyperlinks that execute a VBA macro, which I have achieved by using the `HYPERLINK` function:

```
=HYPERLINK("#AddReview()";"Add Review")
```

Since the HYPERLINK function will not invoke the `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` method, I created my own function as follows (simplified):

```
Public Function AddReview()

  MsgBox Selection.Cells.Row

End Function
```

When the hyperlink is clicked the function does execute successfully, but the problem is that the function executes 3 times until it fails on the third run with the message `Reference isn't valid`.

Does anybody have an idea why it would keep executing? I have not been able to find an answer.

Comment: I've recreated your issue - what I find interesting is the fact I placed `Stop` above your `MsgBox ...` line and execution when right past it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you cannot use the other 'Hyperlink Method'? - The one that would fire the event `FollowHyperlink`?

Comment: I'm guessing you are uncovering something about the call stack. The function is always called 3 times in quick succession irrespective of STOP or Wait commands within. Even conditional logic for Exit Function are ignored.

Comment: @QHarr Yeah, even used `End` which would typically halt all execution - yet the msgbox still showed three times.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Annoying isn't it, cos you can't even inspect the stack!

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I generate the sheet programmatically, so using the function makes my life alot easier. The solution provided by BigBen solved the problem though. Would still be interesting to know why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the root cause, but similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114213/9245853), using `Set AddReview = Selection` fixes the behavior.

```
Public Function AddReview()
    Set AddReview = Selection
    MsgBox Selection.Cells.Row
End Function
```