# How to populate cells in a column with hyperlinks to themselves

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I would like Column AF populated with hyperlinks to themselves up to the last row containing data in column A.

I will then use this link to run the macro that i need and use Target.Cell.Row to get information from this row within the macro.

I have tried to use the code in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33114213/6893569 but i keep getting the error every time i try to run my macro from with this function or call another macro from within it. I have later found that functions cannot call other macros and can only return values.

Any other ideas? I have been looking for over an hour now and trying a different combination of things, including right clicking on the cell, creating hyperlink and using

`Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` to launch the macro and `Target.Range.Row` to get the row number of clicked cell. Then only problem is that i need the hyperlinks (Over 60,000 rows worth) to be auto populated and linked to them selves, it would be ridulcous to do this manually and cant see a way to do this automaticaly unless it was pasting the formula hyperlink in but this cant be used to run the macro for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro of converting one cell to a hyperlink to itself and then trying to modify the code from there?

Comment: Although I'm wondering if there is a better event to launch the macro.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are trying to call?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim AFrange As Range, r As Range, s As String

    Set AFrange = Range("AF1:AF" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each r In AFrange
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & r.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:="myself"
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Based on the comment from ***Pᴇʜ***, use this instead:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim AFrange As Range, r As Range, s As String

    Set AFrange = Range("AF1:AF" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each r In AFrange
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & r.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:="myself"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: It should enclose the sheet name in apostrophes `SubAddress:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & r.Address(0, 0)` just in case the sheet name contains spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`target` in your event is of type `Hyperlink` and has no `Range` property.  It has a `Address` and a `SubAddress`-property - in case a Hyperlink points to a place within the same Workbook, you find the address in `target.SubAddress` - however, that is a string and not a `Range`.

When you set the destination address to the cell itself, you could use `ActiveCell.Row` to get the row - note that when the address is pointing to a different place, Excel will jump to that place first and executes the code after.

To set the Hyperlinks, use `Gary's Student` code (I was about to post the same).

Your sentence *"I have later found that functions cannot call other macros and can only return values"* makes no sense to me - you have an event routine that is a `Sub` (not a `Function`). Plus you can call any other routine from both a Function or a Sub.

The overall question is if it is not better  to use different Worksheet events like `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick` or `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` - there you have a `Range` as target and no need to blow your worksheet with 60K of Hyperlinks